# Import external javascript to Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, charts, ionic2, ionic3, data-visualization

I am facing some problem when try to import javascript library to my Ionic app, specifically import this chart into my ionic project

```
https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart.
```

Firstly I install the latest ionic, after that go to

```
/src/
```

open the assets folder, create a

```
/js/
```

folder inside assets copy .js inside this js folder goto

```
/src/index.html
```

Add path `<script src="assets/js/N.js">`
Go to typescript file and declare var N;

And another way like this video: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWIzZ8wBqk0`

But both of them didn't worked. Do you have any else idea ? Thank you.

Comment: generally you need a typescript type declaration file to import a js library. This one doesnt seem to have one. Also it doesnt look like it has any recent updates.. Suggest you look for an alternate solution

Comment: Yep, I had declare variable like that : declare var easyPieChart:any;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need change your tsconfig.json "declaration": true, like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  "declaration": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "lib": ["dom", "es2015"],
  "module": "es2015",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "target": "es5"
 },
 "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
 "exclude": ["node_modules", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/__tests__/*.ts"],
 "compileOnSave": false,
 "atom": {
   "rewriteTsconfig": false
 }
}
```

and you need create a folder and a file like this 'typings/index.d.ts' in your project

[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThjrV.png)

hope you can understand my poor english

Comment: do we need to name the folder "types" or "typings" ? in text you say typings but in image it says "types"